# How to create validation file for XML with dynamic elements?

Tags: xml, dtd

I need to create validation file (DTD or Schema or whatever) for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
  <StatusCode>1</StatusCode>
  <StatusMessage>
     <SSPReturnMessage>
       <S>false</S>
       <Date>23-Jan-2013 14:33</Date>
       <EL>
         <E EC="473">
            <ES><![CDATA[Error message]]></ES>
         </E>
       </EL>
     </SSPReturnMessage>
  </StatusMessage>
  <Data>
    <LocalPort>-1</LocalPort>
    <TunnelID></TunnelID>
  </Data>
</Result>
```

The Data tag is optinal and the tags inside can be anything (any tag name).
The question is how to do that and which technology to use? DTD or Schema? or even somthing else?

Comment: What do you mean by validate, just the tags or things like a date is a valid date

Comment: Validate means to terse formal syntax that declares precisely which elements and references may appear where in the document of the particular type, and what the elements, contents and attributes are.

Comment: Basically, the main problem is how to dynamicly validate the inside Data tags which are not known from the first place.

Comment: @Mark Maybe I need to use Schema with: <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
That will skip the inside Data tag parsing.

Comment: I know what validate means in the dictionary - but in XML if could mean check it is valid XML, the XML meats a scema or check the data is valid

Comment: The XML meats the schema, data validation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with DTD. You *could* declare `Data` as:

```
<!ELEMENT Data ANY>
```

but any children of `Data` would still need to be declared (which you can't do because you don't know what those elements will be).

I think you're correct and will need to use `xs:any` in XSD.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use XSD as a solution.